# IIS URL Rewrite remove part of path

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

After researching url rewrite and reviewing many posts, I'm still stumped as to why my url rewrite is not working. I am attempting to remove `/carrot/` from the path.

Ex: `https://my.server.com/carrot/mobile/path`

should become: `https://my.server.com/mobile/path`

My URL rewrite rule is pretty simple and looks as follows:

```
    <rule name="RemoveCarrotFromPath">
      <match url=".*carrot(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

All help is appreciated.

**Edit** Below you can find all rules in use in case this is an issue where various rules are clashing:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirectPayment" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/payment" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://my.app.com/carrot/Payment" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="redirectMembership" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/membership" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://my.app.com/carrot/Membership" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RemoveCarrotFromPath">
      <match url=".*carrot(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Rewrite does not change addresses in browsers, so if your goal is to remove something from URLs, don't use rewrite action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue was to use `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite` as follows:

```
<rule name="RemoveCarrotFromPath">
  <match url=".*carrot(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```